# Python mechanize to follow image links?

Tags: python, image, hyperlink, mechanize

mechanize's `Browser` class is great and it's follow_link() function is great too. But what to do with this kind of links:

```
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="…"></a>
```

Is there any way to follow such links? The `text` attribute of this type of links is simply `'[IMG]'`, so AFAIK, there is no way to differentiate such links. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To follow such links you need to add ***nr*** parameter to **follow_link()** method.
Try this:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://www.systempuntoout.com')
for link in br.links():
    print(link)
br.follow_link(text='[IMG]', nr=0)
print br
>>><Browser visiting http://www.systempuntoout.com/quiz>
br.back()
br.follow_link(text='[IMG]', nr=1)
>>><Browser visiting http://www.systempuntoout.com/about>
```